# ASP.NET Role Manager using local machine groups

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-3.5

**Background :**

We have a web application (Forms, .NET 3.5) that users authenticate with using Basic Authentication over HTTPS. This authenticates with the user accounts on the Local Machine. (not an active directory domain).

Users belong to various windows groups based on their privileges. (So Dave could be a member of WebAdministrator)

The application has 100+ stored procedures that have EXECUTE/etc permissions based on the windows group.

**What I need to do :**

I have to change from Basic Authentication to Forms Authentication to allow our users further access to security policies (things such as change password after reset) and to allow specific users of the website to (un)lock users who require it.

**What I have done so far:**

Rather that making all the users create usernames and log in again. (a lot of the data in the database is mapped to the Windows Use). I have created a login page that determines if they are already in the membership table (if so it logs them in). If they are not in the membership, it checks the entered credentials against the windows store and, if valid, creates a membership user based on these details/password and logs them in via that method.

This way, it doesn't create a barrier to logging in, and automatically adds them to the new membership store. This seems to work as expected.

**The Problem:**

Previously, once a user is logged in, various stored procedures are run based on the EXECUTE permissions for that windows group.
Now, I have no way to tell SQL server which membership user belongs to which windows group, and therefore SQL Server has no idea that Dave is a member of WebAdministrator and cannot use execute the stored procedures.

Now there are A LOT of these permissions. What I could do with is someway of mapping an ASPNET Membership role to a windows group. would this work? or am I going about this the wrong way?

I've seen a lot of things about using an Active Directory provider to manage the roles, but these are local machine groups. (Or does Active Directory encompass DOMAIN and WINNT)

Comment: Look into impersonation. This should do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Steve thanks for the heads up. I believed impersonation was a facility for having a whole application impersonate a single user? do you have and link or resource that can help me unfry my brain?